# How to figure out optimum inputs to regression equation given parameters and constraints using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gekko, scipy-optimize-minimize

I need to do some optimization but I have very little experience and not 100% where to start.

Say I have a regression equation;

```
y = exp(intercept + beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2)
```

How could I use scipy.optimize to find the inputs to x1 and x2 that will maximize y given;

```
intercept = 10
beta1 = 1.1
beta2 = 1.2

Constraints;
(x1 + x2) has to be less than 10
x1 has to be greater than x2
```

I don't want to brute force it (i.e. calculate y for every combination of x1 and x2 manually). This is an extremely simple example that I hope to learn and build from.

Comment: Constrained optimization is a wild and wonderful thing. The place to start is to plot the contours of your function to be optimized (i.e., y = ... above), and then draw the constraints on that (just print it out and draw by hand if need be), and look for where the contours show the maximum value, on or within the constraints. (By the way, are there additional constraints x1 > 0 and x2 > 0? Something to consider.) If you get that far let me know and I'll try to offer some more advice. PS. Don't rule out evaluating the function on a grid and looking for the greatest value -- it is a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Robert. Of course, that all makes perfect sense, but my question is about using scipy to do this, syntax and how to set it up for instance. It would be fairly trivial to just write a loop and evaluate the function at every state that meets the constraints.

Comment: From the scipy docs, it looks like maybe [Constrained minimization of multivariate scalar functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize) is a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @RobertDodier I took a look at the docs you suggested. I think I need a solution like linprog(), but it only allows me to specify a linear equation by passing the coefficients as weights. Is there a way to pass a non-linear function like the one in my example?

Comment: Right, linprog allows for linear constraints and a linear objective function, and you need (at the moment) linear constraints and a nonlinear objective. At this I wonder if you might benefit from stepping back a bit and reviewing the conceptual basis and then have another go at the coding aspect. I think a web search should find suitable tutorial resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a package called gekko that can do nonlinear optimization like I needed. Full docs for the package can be found here; [Gekko Documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

Here's the code I used to solve my simple example problem:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko

# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=0,ub=10) 
x2 = m.Var(value=1,lb=0,ub=10) 

# Init the coefficients
alpha = m.Const(value=7) 
beta1 = m.Const(value=1.01) 
beta2 = m.Const(value=1.02) 

# Inequality constraints
m.Equation(x1 + x2 <= 10)
m.Equation(x2 < x1)

m.Obj(-1 * m.exp(alpha + x1*beta1 + x2*beta2)) # Objective
m.options.IMODE = 3 # Steady state optimization set to 3, change to 1 for integer
m.solve() # Solve
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Here is a comparison between Scipy.optimize.minimize and Gekko for another simple problem: https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonOptimization